# Disable the last line at the end of algorithm

Tags: algorithms, rules

If I use the algorithm package as such

```
\begin{algorithm}[h!]
...insert algorithm here...
\end{algorithm}
```

I find a line at the end of my algorithm. Without going into detail, I want a algorithm without the end line. How is it possible to remove the line at the end of a algorithm?

Here is an example of one of my algorithms:

[image]

And here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{foo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State bar
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look at the Section 4.3 of the documentation of the `algorithm` package to see other appearances customization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`algorithm` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) defines the `algorithm` environment/float using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float). As such, you can restyle it using its tools.

You can define an new float style, say `nobottomruled`, which removes the "post" (rule) construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@nobottomruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{}% Formerly \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother

\floatstyle{nobottomruled}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{foo}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State bar
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove the border of your algorithm, and then manually can put horizontal lines above and below of the row heading of algorithm. Here is the way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{foo}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State bar
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP uses [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx). Also, your answer doesn't show how to add the horizontal rules.